# Magento wysiwyg editor not working (tinymce not showing)

Tags: magento

In my Magento admin panel when editing the page or anything else like product descr. the editor is not showing up. I did enable it by default and also clicking the button show editor does not help.

In firebug I get this 404 :

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mydomain.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/magento/editor_plugin.js"

I already reinstalled the tinymce core but this did not help, also nothing to find on google..
Anyone ?

Comment: Any Solutions found?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i solved my problem by following the below mentioned steps:-

- Login to Admin Panel
- System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Javascript Settings >  Merge JavaScript Files > No

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is seems from the side of JS Conflicts if Magento is merging them, for sure we will select no option for JS merge in admin the problem will be resolved, However this will cause a issue with optimization and Google insigt as the all the JS files will not be compressed in case of System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Javascript Settings > Merge JavaScript Files > No

So We must need to keep yes in the admin and we need to resolve the JS conflict issue else it will cause the issue with the site performance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check if the file is accessible or not directly in the browser first.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.example.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/magento/editor_plugin.js"

I doubt something is wrong in the path you specified to load js file.